# Seem to have broken Spyder via Anaconda update (?)

Tags: anaconda, conda, spyder

I (newb) run Spyder via Anaconda, and I seem to have broken it (perhaps after an Anaconda update).

Aside from my code not running, I get this error when running conda list:

"File ~\anaconda3\Lib\re_parser.py:402 in _escape

raise source.error("incomplete escape %s" % escape, len(escape))

error: incomplete escape \U"

Interestingly, I can run conda list in the Anaconda Prompt just fine.

I've tried downgrading Spyder, completely uninstalling Anaconda and all aspects of Spyder, and I've even created a separate user account on my machine, redownloaded Anaconda, same thing.

I'm perplexed, any thoughts?